# Can I use MD5 or similar fast hashes in my example? (no password check)

Tags: security, hash

I need some hash/encryption function that is:

- very fast (my server needs to handle a lot of requests)
- collisions do not matter that much (one collision every 1.000 seeds would be ok)
- secure

The seed is a public variable + some hidden string I can freely choose but this string has to be constant. The output will be public but not saved in a database. But it's good to assume that an attacker could access every output from every input (he can alter the public variable which goes into the input seed).

So how can I make this safe (hide the hidden string from the hash seed)? I can't use password hashes as they are too slow (as I said I need to handle a lot of requests per second). I do not have to use the whole ouput hash (the first 3 characters would do the job) but this is not safe as the attacker could parallely check for several matches. So would it be safe to just use a very long hidden string (I think it's called pepper in cryptography)?

**Edit:** The purpose is to convert a URL X to a URL Y. Y has to be different from X which is done by adding a string S. S must not collide for a given 1000 urls. I want to convert many URLs X0, X1, X2, ..., Xn to URLs Y0, Y1, Y2, ..., Yn. This conversion has to be fast. It must be practically impossible to find out the algorithm that converts X to Y. X and Y are public.

Comment: The question is: What are you doing? Please explain the overall problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I added some information to the op.

Comment: It must be practically impossible to find out the *algorithm* that converts X to Y? This idea is flawed (security by obscurity) if I understand correctly. Also maybe it's just me but I still don't get the usecase. You are writing about a proposed solution, but what is it supposed to be good for? In other words, what are you trying to protect against?